# HTML Form Data into Flask Script using APIs

Tags: python, api, flask, submit, forms, http-post

i'm trying to get my python script below working as a dynamic web application that uses a HTML form for users to type in a certain carpark number which would then return the information about the number of lots available for that given carpark based on a Government-Website's API.

Python Script:

```
import requests
import json

# Do the HTTP get request
response = requests.get("https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/transport/carpark-availability")

jack = response.json()
daniel = jack['items'][0]["carpark_data"]

for d in daniel:
    if d["carpark_number"] == carpark_No:
        print("\nFor Carpark No. " + carpark_No + ":\n")
        print(d["carpark_info"])
```

I want the variable "carpark_No" to be a user_inputted value from a HTML Form.

E.g. If i set "carpark_No" to be "HG55", my output from this script will be:

```
For Carpark No. HG55:

[ { 'total_lots': '82' , 'lot_type': 'C', 'lots_available': '79'} ]
```

However, this python script is completely terminal based as you may have guessed. I want this to work as a dynamic web app that allows users to return carpark lot information from an API. I researched into Flask and managed to get the following working on localhost.

Main Flask App:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def student():
   return render_template('student.html')

@app.route('/result',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def result():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      result = request.form
      return render_template("result.html",result = result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

Flask App1: # after starting python script above and opening localhost:5000 on browser. (student.html)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <body>

      <form action = "http://localhost:5000/result" method = "POST">
         <p>Carpark No: <input type = "text" name = "Carpark" /></p>
         <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>
      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

Flask App2:  (result.html)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <body>

      <table border = 1>
         {% for key, value in result.items() %}

            <tr>
               <th> {{ key }} </th>
               <td> {{ value }} </td>
            </tr>

         {% endfor %}
      </table>

   </body>
</html>
```

The problem with the flask scripts above is that I can plug in my values of "Carpark_No" as "HG55" and it perfectly returns me the data in a table but that's not what I want.

I would like to change my Main Flask App script in a way that will enable the final page at "/results" to be a rendered page of the Python Script I had going for me at the start.

In other words, I would like to use the data from my form submission in student.html and plug it into my first Python Script so I would get an output like this:

```
For Carpark No. HG55: # should be dynamic data that can be changed from student.html or Flask App 1

[ { 'total_lots': '82' , 'lot_type': 'C', 'lots_available': '79'} ]
```

However, I haven't the faintest idea of where to start, could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need two routes, can just use one since it has two modes:

```
@app.route('/',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def main():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      result = request.form
      return render_template("result.html", result=result)
   else:
      return render_template("student.html")
```

then you can post the form back to the main route,

```
   <form action = "{{ url_for('main') }}" method="POST">
         <p>Carpark No: <input type = "text" name = "Carpark" /></p>
         <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>
   </form>
```

Your problem, though, is that you are just recycling the form input data and passing it to result.html. Instead you want to process the form input data akin to your script and then return the processed data:

```
import requests
import json

@app.route('/',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
        def main():
           if request.method == 'POST':
              data = request.form
              # do your original script
              response = requests.get("https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/transport/carpark-availability")
              jack = response.json()
              daniel = jack['items'][0]["carpark_data"]
              # cross reference against form input
              result = {'Carpark No.': data['Carpark']}
              for d in daniel:
                  if d["carpark_number"] == data['Carpark']:
                      result.update({'Carpark Info': d["carpark_info"]})
              return render_template("result.html", result=result)
           else:
              return render_template("student.html")
```

Comment: I've tried "data.Carpark.data" and data.Carpark and data.Carpark.value but they all return "ImmutableMultiDict Object has no attribute 'Carpark' " ; How then should I edit my code to access the form input data? @Attack68

Comment: edited: just use data['Carpark'] instead. If you learn to debug python script you can pause the execution and analyze the 'data' object to see what you should do. Failing that you can also try a print(data) function to get a read out of what its keys/attributes might be